# Capturing git commit date (--format=%ci) in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, escaping

Currently, for my C++ projects, I run a pre-compile operation that writes a separate header file that captures the git hash of the build, effectively giving me the ability to see exactly which commit any instance of a program is running from as it's running.

So far something like this works:

```bat
set file="%~dp0git_sha1.h"
echo #ifndef git_sha1H > %file%
echo #define git_sha1H >> %file%

set cmd=git rev-parse HEAD
set git_sha1=#define GIT_SHA1
for /f %%i in ('%cmd%') do set "git_sha1=%git_sha1% "%%i""
echo %git_sha1% >> %file%

echo #endif >> %file%
```

Now I'm attempting to add the HEAD's commit date which would be done with: `git show -s --format=%ci HEAD`

However, when duplicating the middle section to accommodate this command I run into all sorts of errors like `fatal: ambiguous argument 'ci': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`, `unknown pretty format 'ci'`, etc.

I narrowed this down to unescaped characters in the for-loop and came up with something like this

```bat
set cmd2=git show -s --format^=%%ci HEAD
set git_date=#define GIT_DATE
for /f %%i in ('%cmd2%') do set "git_date=%git_date% "%%i""
echo %git_date% >> %file%
```

However, this STILL gives me `fatal: ambiguous argument '%ci: unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

I read this as the escaped `^=` is not being properly passed into git so that it's seeing `--format %ci HEAD` rather than `--format=%ci HEAD`, but I'm not entirely sure where I'm off here, especially when a separate `echo %cmd2%` debug line does show the correct command.

Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend switching to PowerShell.

Comment: I definitely would like to learn it if I can find some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd suggest you write your code, to appropriately use doublequotes and to write out to your `.h` file:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "file=%~dp0git_sha1.h"
Set "cmd=git rev-parse HEAD"
Set "git_sha1=#define GIT_SHA1"
Set "cmd2=git show -s --format=%%ci HEAD"
Set "git_date=#define GIT_DATE"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('%cmd%')Do Set "git_sha1=%git_sha1% "%%A""
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('%cmd2%')Do Set "git_date=%git_date% "%%A""

(Echo #ifndef git_sha1H
    Echo #define git_sha1H
    Echo %git_sha1%
    Echo %git_date%
    Echo #endif)>"%file%"
```

Please note that I've just added your `%cmd2%` output before the `#endif` in your output file.

Comment: A lot cleaner! I like it and will probably rewrite mine to use it. However, running this as is still gives the same `Ambiguous argument '%ci': unkown revision...` error as before. Are you sure cmd2 doesn't need to be escaped somehow?

Comment: @depwl9992, when a [tag:for-loop] runs your command it does so by passing it to run inside a new cmd.exe instance. It is possible that when cmd.exe parses it, one or more characters could cause issues. I haven't got a PC to try anything on, but you could try using this syntax, `('^"%cmd%^"')`, `('^"%cmd2%^"')` to see if it's one or more characters in your command is/was causing the error.

Comment: That did it. In addition to adding escaped quotes in the for-loop, I also had to escape the = in the set: `set "cmd2=git show -s --format^=%%ci HEAD"`. I also found out that I could have double-escaped it like: `set cmd2=git show -s --format^^=%%ci HEAD` without quotes, but that goes against what you stated earlier about "appropriately using doublequotes," which I definitely need to figure out all the nuances of.

Comment: [The final version](https://pastebin.com/Lf0V6G4F) for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In order to follow the syntax used everywhere else you should change `set git_date_temp=%git_date: =%` to `set "git_date_temp=%git_date: =%"`.